# Windows 7 Unattended install - Not really 'unattended'

Tags: windows-7, sysprep, unattended

I have been trying for a few days to get a correct and working Unattended.xml answerfile for Windows 7. Trying to create a completely unattended install of Windows 7 to where a tech can insert USB drive, boot from it, and wait for the setup to complete. The image I am working from has already been sysprepped with the unattended answer file, and at every change since then. It is a time consuming process, because WDS/Server installs are not an option, only this method of pre-imaged USB devices.

I have been all over technet, Serverfault (and other StackExchange sites), random blogs and such sites attempting different answerfile options that would (should/supposedly) create a completley unattended install.

Using WSIM to manage/write/modify/check the answerfile and DISM to manage the image.

Regardless of ANY options I put in WinPE pass, the following ALWAYS happens:

- PE asks for language/locale/
- PE Displays EULA Agreement
- PE Disk configuration always displays, prompting for partitioning

**I need the setup to begin, process, and complete without asking the user ANYTHING**

The most recent XML answerfile I have is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
        </SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
        <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
        <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DiskConfiguration>
        <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        <Disk wcm:action="add">
        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
            <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
            <CreatePartitions>
            <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
            <Order>1</Order>
            <Size>100</Size>
                <Type>Primary</Type>
            </CreatePartition>
         <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
            <Order>2</Order>
                <Type>Primary</Type>
                <Extend>true</Extend>
            </CreatePartition>
            </CreatePartitions>
            <ModifyPartitions>
            <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Format>NTFS</Format>
                <Label>System</Label>
                <Order>1</Order>
            <Active>true</Active>
                <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
            </ModifyPartition>
            <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Format>NTFS</Format>
                <Label>OS</Label>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
            </ModifyPartition>
            </ModifyPartitions>
        </Disk>
        </DiskConfiguration>
        <ImageInstall>
        <OSImage>
            <InstallTo>
            <DiskID>0</DiskID>
            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
            </InstallTo>
        <InstallFrom>
            <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                <Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </MetaData>
            </InstallFrom>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        </OSImage>
        </ImageInstall>
        <UserData>
          <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
        <ProductKey>
            <Key>----</Key>
            <WillShowUI>----</WillShowUI>
        </ProductKey>
        <FullName>----</FullName>
        <Organization>----</Organization>
        </UserData>
    </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
        <TimeZone>----</TimeZone>
        <ProductKey>----</ProductKey>
        <RegisteredOrganization>----</RegisteredOrganization>
        <RegisteredOwner>----</RegisteredOwner>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RunSynchronous>
        <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
            <Path>net user administrator /active:yes</Path>
            <Order>1</Order>
        </RunSynchronousCommand>
        </RunSynchronous>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
    </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OOBE>
        <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
        <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
        <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
        <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
        </OOBE>
        <RegisteredOrganization>----</RegisteredOrganization>
        <RegisteredOwner>----</RegisteredOwner>
        <TimeZone>TZ</TimeZone>
        <UserAccounts>
        <AdministratorPassword>
            <Value>aBcDe</Value>
            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
        </AdministratorPassword>
        <LocalAccounts>
            <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
            <Password>
                <Value>aBcDe</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </Password>
            <Description>Local Administrator</Description>
            <DisplayName>Administrator</DisplayName>
            <Group>Administrators</Group>
            <Name>Administrator</Name>
            </LocalAccount>
        </LocalAccounts>
        </UserAccounts>
        <AutoLogon>
        <Password>
            <Value>aBCdE</Value>
            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
        </Password>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <LogonCount>5</LogonCount>
        <Username>administrator</Username>
        <Domain></Domain>
        </AutoLogon>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
        <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
    </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:wimfile#Windows 7 Professional" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Does anyone else have experience with such a situation occurring, or know how to correct my answerfile so that it truly becomes unattended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by putting the unattend.xml on the root of the USB drive, and renaming it to autounattend.xml. After that change, the Windows 7 setup proceeds unattended as I was lead to believe it should have, with the unattend.xml in the sysprep directory of the install.wim.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to downlaod the [MDT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791) kit, so you dont have to manualy edit the xml file?

Comment: I have the MDT kit, and the WAIK. As stated, I use Windows System Image Manager to edit/write the answerfile.

Answer (score 1):

I used this guide when I started with Win 7 images and found it very helpful:
http://theitbros.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-%E2%80%93-start-to-finish

If I remember correctly when you sysprep it copies the xml to somewhere in the  system32 folder and uses that copy for the rest of the setup.

Posting my phone, sry if this is off.